# i want to convert my aspx.cs to dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

i have a default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="clicke here" OnClick="btn_Click"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and default.aspx.cs :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string test;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        test = txt.Text;
        lbl.Text = test;

    }
}
```

now i want to make the dll of my default.aspx.cs file and remove it from the website and give the reference of it.

so how can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on Properties. Then go to the Application tab and change output type to class library.

[image]

Once the dll is created in bin folder, right click on Reference in your project where you want to add the dll. And then add the reference of the dll.

Comment: i dont see any application tab in properties... i am using vs 2012

Comment: @jayrathod:- Added an image. Hope that helps!

Comment: @jayrathod:- Did you tried to use [IL Merge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) Also check this:-http://www.msdotnet.co.in/2012/08/how-can-create-dll-file-and-use-it-in.html#.U_jAgcQW1tI

Comment: no..can you please explain what it IL Merge?? i dont know anything about it

Comment: @jayrathod:- The link has the explanation. However if I understood correctly then you want to create a class library and use that in your web application?

Comment: yes...i have saw many applications in that they have only aspx file and that codebehind is in dll file.

Comment: @jayrathod:- Indeed thats how you will find that most of the applications are running but for that you need to create the class library of your project which you want and the step is same which I mentioned above!

Comment: but how can i find that lable , button and textbox in that class library ??

Comment: @jayrathod:- I didnt get that? Hope you are clear what is a class library and what is a dll

Comment: @jayrathod:- Great. Then all you need to do is the step which is mentioned in the answer and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be best to create a server control. You can then use it in any ASP.NET Project.

Here is a walkthrough...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yhzc935f(v=vs.100).aspx